# how to apply a texture to multiple objects?

Tags: texturing

I wonder if it is possible to apply a texture to multiple objects and how can i do this?

i searche on google and youtube for an answer but until now without success.

Comment: If you want to copy a material, select the object(s) with no material, then the object with the material you want to copy, then ctrl L > Materials. But if your material contains an Image Texture node, it means you'll have to unwrap your object(s).

Comment: You can't apply textures to objects, multiple or single, you apply textures to materials